# How to make a JLabel looks like a tab header of JTabbedPane

Tags: java, background, jlabel

Providing the text of the JLabel is "Text",

I want a JLabel object looks like this in Nimbus:

[image]

like this in Metal:

[image]

i.e. the same as a tab header of a JTabbedPane.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely Yes. But not that easy.

Every Swing Component has a UI associated with it, that can be overridden by your own custom UI. You can create a JLabelUI (UI delegate class) and set it yourself, or you could simply override the paint() method of the JLabel (creating your own custom JLabel.

The next step is then to get the source of the UI that you want to copy, and take the paint function from that UI and copy it into your overridden paint method (or UI delegate class).

Comment: The first step is easy, but how to do the second step?

Comment: Here is an example of the BasicLabelUI http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.java.htm. The MetalLabelUI simply extends this and overrides the paintDisabledText method http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLabelUI.java.htm.

Comment: Thanks. But that's the first step, how to draw a JLabel. But I want to know how to get the background of the tab(i.e. the source)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another solution's logic is more easy;

put JLabel into a JPanel. set JPanel's background as you wish (image, drawing with graphics etc.) and setText to JLabel. Create a widget with them and use it ;)

Note: I think @Codemwnci 's method is more acceptable ;)